# Google reports some 404 errors that do not actually exist. Does it indicate that my website is hacked?

Tags: php, mysql, url, http-status-code-404

When I check my website status in Google's webmasters/tools, it lists some url's as 404 errors such as:

`www.example.com/mysqli.mysqli`

or

`www.example.com/mysqli.query`

I have designed the website with PHP and have used some MySQL queries in it.
I'm wondering from where these errors do stem? Or, does it indicate that my website is probably hacked? Is it a serious problem or could be just ignored?

thanks

Comment: Most likely it is just an automated script looking for weaknesses in your website, they often trawl through loads of websites. I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: What Conn says makes sense. If that's the case, you could setup a method to log the query and inform them via a header, that their IP address has been logged. You can then use those logs to block them in `.htaccess`

Comment: but why does it appear in google's webmasters tools? from where does google get those urls?

Comment: *That,* I couldn't tell you, since it's never happened to me nor have I been faced with that before, therefore I can't give you a definite answer. You will need to continue your research.

Comment: See my comment above yours; I don't know. Edit: You deleted your comment.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks fred, especially for suggesting blocking their ip address via .htaccess

Comment: You're welcome. Keep in mind that these IP addresses can change. However, if you see a lot of activity coming from let's say: 123.4.5.6 then 123.4.6.7 then you can block using `123.4.` - Every IP under `123.4.x.x` will be blocked.

Comment: This is what [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) is all about. If configured correctly it will block IPs that are behaving badly.

Comment: Another thing to protect your queries with and if you're not already using them, are [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

Answer (score 2):

This would be automated attempts at finding weaknesses in websites. Since, they returned 404 errors, it means that your website does not have these files, so you are safe.

You would probably be surprised how many of these kinds of hacking attempts happen to just about every website... they serve as a reminder that you need to be careful what you actually expose to the web.